# Does Swift support MRC?

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting

I wonder if Swift supports MRC or only ARC.

I know that iOS use two memory management models: ARC and MRC. But can I create an app using manual reference counting or is it only available in Objective-C?

Comment: No, Swift only uses automatic memory management. Is there a particular reason you’d want to use manual memory management, if it were available?

Comment: *”I know that iOS use two memory management models”* - it’s not the OS, it’s the programming language.

Comment: @Alexander No, i just want to improve my memory management knowledge. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift only supports automatic reference counting. ARC is baked into the language.

As somebody who wrote Objective-C code using MRC for years, I can say with confidence: ARC is a big improvement on MRC.

MRC is fussy and error-prone.